# Vb: Read only 1st line from text file

Tags: vb.net

I am using a file reader, that displays choices in a TextBox according to a txt file. 
However, I want to make it display each choice by line, not by string length, as different choices will be added each time. How do I replace `SubString`, by line 1, 2, etc?

My code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\user1\Dekstop\select.txt").Substring(0, 20)
    TextBox2.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\select.txt").Substring(22, 23)
    TextBox3.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\select.txt").Substring(45, 12)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form1.txtServer.Text = TextBox1.Text
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Same for other textBoxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) reads all lines of the file and put them into an array.

```
Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\user1\Dekstop\select.txt")
TextBox1.Text = lines(0)
TextBox2.Text = lines(1)
TextBox3.Text = lines(2)
```